# Minikube Dashboard not found Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I tried running `minikube dashboard` on my local cluster but kept getting error below

```
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Error validating service: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: services "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

I ran `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide` and the kube addon manager appears to be running as shown below but the `minikube dashboard` command wouldn't work

**Minikube addon manager**

```
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube             1/1       Running   1          57m       192.168.99.101   minikube
```

**minikube version**

`minikube version: v0.25.0`

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.2", GitCommit:"5fa2db2bd46ac79e5e00a4e6ed24191080aa463b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-18T21:11:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"", Minor:"", GitVersion:"v1.9.0", GitCommit:"925c127ec6b946659ad0fd596fa959be43f0cc05", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-01-26T19:04:38Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**minikube dashboard --logtostderr --v=5**

```
W0207 11:05:19.107001   56449 root.go:148] Error reading config file at /Users/innocentanigbo/.minikube/config/config.json: open /Users/innocentanigbo/.minikube/config/config.json: no such file or directory
I0207 11:05:19.108690   56449 notify.go:109] Checking for updates...
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Error validating service: Error getting service kubernetes-dashboard: services "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

Comment: Can you update question with `minikube version` & `kubectl version`

Comment: there should be a pod with `kubernetes-dashboard-` prefix

Comment: @aerokite see minikube and kubectl version added in amended. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @abu Hanifa No I can't see any pod named `kubernetes-dashboard`. How do you get this pod? does it come with a different image? In the past before I changed to my current new laptop, i can always access the dashboard after `minikube start`

Comment: @InnocentAnigbo can you add output of `minikube dashboard --logtostderr --v=5` to your question?

Comment: @abu hanifa - added output of command to question.

Comment: @InnocentAnigbo Do you try `delete minkube` and again `minikube start`?

Comment: Yes did that already. Plus im running latest version of minikube. The details of the dashboard changes to this version is here https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/2409 but i can't see `kubernetes dashboard` pod in my deployment